# Error generating Hyperledger Fabric network v-1.2

Tags: networking, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am trying to generate a network with the version 1.2 (it has to be this version) with the "fist-network" sample, but my orderer container doesn´t start.

My Docker images are all in version 1.2.

I try to start my network:

```
$ ./byfn.sh up -t 3000 -i 1.2.0
Starting for channel 'mychannel' with CLI timeout of '3000' seconds and CLI delay of '3' seconds
Continue? [Y/n] y
proceeding ...
LOCAL_VERSION=1.2.0
DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION=1.2.0
```

But the orderer container is created but doesn't start:

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                    COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                                              NAMES
be721b8a14ae        hyperledger/fabric-tools:amd64-1.2.0     "/bin/bash"         32 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds                                                                  cli
bdf9dbac2b0b        hyperledger/fabric-peer:amd64-1.2.0      "peer node start"   37 seconds ago      Up 32 seconds               0.0.0.0:10051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:10053->7053/tcp   peer1.org2.example.com
0c9c8ca1c8d7        hyperledger/fabric-orderer:amd64-1.2.0   "orderer"           37 seconds ago      Exited (2) 31 seconds ago                                                      orderer.example.com
d74f026da522        hyperledger/fabric-peer:amd64-1.2.0      "peer node start"   37 seconds ago      Up 32 seconds               0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     peer0.org1.example.com
a51cbf695a24        hyperledger/fabric-peer:amd64-1.2.0      "peer node start"   37 seconds ago      Up 32 seconds               0.0.0.0:9051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9053->7053/tcp     peer0.org2.example.com
e8dbd666d0dd        hyperledger/fabric-peer:amd64-1.2.0      "peer node start"   37 seconds ago      Up 32 seconds               0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     peer1.org1.example.com
```

This is an extract or the log:

```
2018-11-28 08:52:48.881 UTC [fsblkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> INFO 004 Getting block information from block storage
2018-11-28 08:52:48.920 UTC [orderer/commmon/multichannel] checkResourcesOrPanic -> CRIT 005 [channel byfn-sys-channel] config requires unsupported channel capabilities: Channel capability V1_3 is required but not supported: Channel capability V1_3 is required but not supported
panic: [channel byfn-sys-channel] config requires unsupported channel capabilities: Channel capability V1_3 is required but not supported: Channel capability V1_3 is required but not supported
```

I can't understand why it is looking for version 1.3 channel, if all the images and containers are version 1.2. 
Do you have any insight in this?